# Perl, XML::Twig, how to reading field with the same tag

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I'm working on processing a XML file I receive from a partner. I do not have any influence on changing the makeup of this xml file. An extract of the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
  <object>
    <id>VW-XJC9</id>
    <name>Name</name>
    <type>House</type>
    <description>
    <![CDATA[<p>some descrioption of the house</p>]]> </description>
    <localcosts>
      <localcost>
        <type>mandatory</type>
        <name>What kind of cost</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[Some text again, different than the first tag]]>
        </description>
      </localcost>
    </localcosts>
  </object>
</objects>
```

The reason I use Twig is that this XML is about 11GB big, about 100000 different objects) . The problem is when I reach the localcosts part, the 3 fields (type, name and description) are skipped, probably because these names are already used before.

The code I use to go through the xml file is as follows:

```
my $twig= new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { 
                 id                            => \&get_ID,
                 name                          => \&get_Name,
                 type                          => \&get_Type,
                 description                   => \&get_Description,
                 localcosts                    => \&get_Localcosts
});

$lokaal="c:\\temp\\data3.xml";
getstore($xml, $lokaal);
$twig->parsefile("$lokaal");

sub get_ID          { my( $twig, $data)= @_;  $field[0]=$data->text; $twig->purge; } 
sub get_Name        { my( $twig, $data)= @_;  $field[1]=$data->text; $twig->purge; }
sub get_Type        { my( $twig, $data)= @_;  $field[3]=$data->text; $twig->purge; }
sub get_Description { my( $twig, $data)= @_;  $field[8]=$data->text; $twig->purge; }
sub get_Localcosts{

  my ($t, $item) = @_;

  my @localcosts = $item->children;
  for my $localcost ( @localcosts ) {
    print "$field[0]: $localcost->text\n";
    my @costs = $localcost->children;
    for my $cost (@costs) {
      $Type       =$cost->text if $cost->name eq q{type};
      $Name       =$cost->text if $cost->name eq q{name};
      $Description=$cost->text if $cost->name eq q{description};
      print "Fields: $Type, $Name, $Description\n";
    }
  }
  $t->purge;    
}
```

when I run this code, the main fields are read without issues, but when the code arrives at the 'localcosts' part, the second for-next loop is not executed. When I change the field names in the xml to  unique ones, this code works perfectly.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want the handlers for type, name and desctiption only be triggered in the object tag, specify the path:

```
my $twig = new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { 
                 id                    => \&get_ID,
                 'object/name'         => \&get_Name,
                 'object/type'         => \&get_Type,
                 'object/description'  => \&get_Description,
                 localcosts            => \&get_Localcosts
    });
```

Comment: Hi Choroba, Thanks, this works! I tried this solution with the field of the lcoalcosts but that did not work. But this does! Super!

Comment: Your other fields should look like `localcost/type`, `localcost/name` etc. At a guess you were using `localcosts/type`? You *could* use `localcosts/localcost/type` but there's no need

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `id`, `name`, `type` and `description` handlers *are* being executed for both occurrences. You will find that the contents of the `@fields` is from the `localcost` values, as the data from the `object` values has been overwritten.

Also, in handling the `localcost` elements, the handlers have done a $twig->purge, which removes the data from memory. So when the `localcosts` handler is called it finds the element empty

I think the easiest way to do this is to write a *single* handler that processes each `object` node in one go and then purges it

This program demonstrates. Note that I have used `Data::Dumper` only so that you can see the contents of `@fields` once it has been populated

It is *very important* that you `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program, especially if you are asking for help with it. It is a simple measure that can reveal many straightforward errors that you may otherwise waste a lot of time searching for

Note also that the "indirect object" form of method calls is discouraged: you should write `XML::Twig->new(...)` instead of `new XML::Twig (...)`.

And if you use single quotes instead of double quotes then a backslash inside a string doesn't need to be doubled-up unless it is the last character of the string. But Perl is quite happy if you use forward slashes as a path separator, even on Windows

I hope this helps

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

my $twig= XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { object => \&get_Object });

my $lokaal = 'c:\temp\data3.xml';

my @fields;
$twig->parsefile($lokaal);


sub get_Object {

  my ($twig, $object) = @_;

  $fields[0] = $object->findvalue('id');
  $fields[1] = $object->findvalue('name');
  $fields[3] = $object->findvalue('type');
  $fields[8] = $object->findvalue('description');

  print Dumper \@fields;

  my @localcosts = $object->findnodes('localcosts/localcost');

  for my $localcost (@localcosts) {

    my $type        = $localcost->findvalue('type');
    my $name        = $localcost->findvalue('name');
    my $description = $localcost->findvalue('description');

    print "$type, $name, $description\n";
  }

  $twig->purge;    
}
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = [
          "VW-XJC9",
          "Name",
          undef,
          "House",
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          "<p>some descrioption of the house</p> "
        ];
mandatory, What kind of cost, Some text again, different than the first tag
```

Comment: Hi Borodin, this looks like a very nice solution. THis will take me some time to rewrite the module I have, but I like this idea. It's very tidy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2970543: I'm pleased that it helped you. You need to do a lot of work with the more complex libraries like `XML::Tiwg` before the best technique for a given situation becomes apparent

Answer (score 2):

As Borodin said, if you have handlers on `name`, `type` and `description`, and you call `$twig->purge` at the end of each handler, then the elements are removed from the tree. You could set a handler on `object`, that only does a `$twig->purge` call, and you would be OK.

You don't need to call `purge` "too often", just make sure you call it at a low enough level so you don't use too much memory. There is no point really in calling it for each single leaf element.

That's a common mistake, one that I make myself quite often ;--(.